# Scribd Developer Challenge: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to learn a bit of JavScript and Hack on the Scribed Developer Challenge, However, I can't get even the most basic thing to work.

Here is the Javascript I have:

```
function new_game() {
}

function make_move() {

  var board = get_board();
  var lat = get_my_x();
  var longt = get_my_y();
  trace("("+ lat + "," + longt + ")")

   // we found an item! take it!
   if (board[get_my_x()][get_my_y()] > 0) {
       return TAKE;
   }

   var rand = Math.random() * 4;

   if (rand < 1) return NORTH;
   if (rand < 2) return SOUTH;
   if (rand < 3) return EAST;
   if (rand < 4) return WEST;

   return PASS;

}
```

And my output looks like this:

[image]

The weird thing is that the robot went in a straight line up and so he(the green one) is currently in what I would call position(1,9). However, the output reads (4,0).  Here is how they map.

(4,0) => (1,7)
(5,0) => (1,8)
(4,0) => (1,9)

It doesn't seem to me to have any correspondence, and appears random. If you need more you can find the [API online](http://www.scribd.com/jobs/botrace_api) as well as a [testing framework on github](https://github.com/scribd/robot-fruit-hunt).

Am I calling get_my_x and get_my_y correctly?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

[image]

My green robot started on the same tile as the purple robot. The first move was up and the output was (2,2). The second bove was back down the output was (2,1). Then it moved to the left and the output was (2,2). How can this be? Two grid tiles with the same coordinates!

Comment: @Daedalus added explicit question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this although it is a little embarrassing:

Essentially, I wanted the output number to tell me where I was at, instead of my last position. I had the wrong expectations, and once that is solved it all makes sense.